# Crystal Reports - Summarize Cross Tab Values

Tags: crystal-reports, crosstab, cumulative-sum

I'm using CR12 pulling from a database and trying to create a summary that will total values in a cross tab.  Here is my scenario:

1. Report detail shows equipment used
2. Detail is grouped by Room and then Date/Time of session
3. Summary section totals up all equipment with discounts, tax, etc.,(via formulas) ending in Grand Total
4. Grand total is then divided by a distinct count of billing codes to calculate avg. $ amount per billing code that is due per room/date-time

This was placed in a cross tab to show Billing Code and $ Amount Due per billing code.  Now I need either another cross tab or summary at the bottom of the report to show the total amount due per billing code.

*Example:*

**Room/Date**----**Billing Code**----**Amount Per Code**

```
101 3/2/16------ABC123----------------$50.00

101 3/2/16------DEF456----------------$50.00

102 3/2/16------ABC123----------------$25.00
```

**TOTAL**

```
  ABC123: $75.00

  DEF456: $50.00
```

Here is a screenshot example of what I have so far:

[Report Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ5LY.jpg)

Any insight provided is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you took a cross tab to show the individual summaries (though it can be done without a cross tab and it is more easy to show final totals in footer as well)

In report footer as well take another cross tab to show summary just take rows as billing codes and sum the amount.. which will do the task